# Connected graph is equivalent to connected realization

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

In this book 
https://books.google.de/books?id=amP7CAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Trees+serre&hl=ro&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

at page 15, the following remark appears:
A graph is connected if and only if its realization is connected.

Is this fact obvious? Could someone explain it in more detail? Geom

Answer (score 2):

Every path in the graph induces a path in its topological realization. On the other hand every component of the graph induces a clopen set in the realization. Therefore, the components of the graph naturally correspond to the components of the realization (and these are clopen).